# How Display data in asp.net Like www.visualthesaurus.com display Thesaurus

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to visually display my data on asp.net website as [www.visualthesaurus.com](http://www.visualthesaurus.com) display for thesaurus. When the user click on the node then next child node displayed
I want to know is this possible in asp.net. Give me some idea or any api by which we can achieve this functionality in our website. Some sourcecode also welcome.

Comment: This is an overly broad question - we'll try to help you solve specific problems but you can't seriously expect people to just hand you a complete rewrite of a commercial website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have written it in Java.

Asp.net is a server side language and could be used to do the server side code. But thats the easy part.

To do a front end like that using pure html / javascript might be possible if you were very good. I would use JQuery to do the graphics and animation, cos that makes it easy to deal with these tricky areas cross-browser.

You would have to really craft your code to be as optimised as possible to get any sort of performance out of javascript.

Maybe silverlight could do it.. I dont know much about it.